# PowerShell script changing file association of tiff and tiff files

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been trying to make a bat script or PowerShell script changing file association of .tif and .tiff files to the MSP program in Modi.

My current bad code looks like this and it doesn't open the file with the Microsoft MSP Program correctly

```
assoc .tif=TIFImage.Document
ftype TIFImage.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MODI\12.0\MSPVIEW.exe" "%1"

assoc .tiff=TIFImage.Document
ftype TIFImage.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MODI\12.0\MSPVIEW.exe" "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`assoc` and `ftype` are CMD-builtin commands, not external programs, so you need to run them via `cmd /c` if you want to use them from PowerShell. Also, PowerShell does funky stuff when parsing the arguments to the `ftype` command, so you need the "magic parameter" (`--%`) to stop it from doing that.

```
cmd /c assoc .tif=TIFImage.Document
cmd /c assoc .tiff=TIFImage.Document
cmd /c --% ftype TIFImage.Document="C:\Pro...IEW.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: What do you mean "a PowerShell equivalent"? That *is* the code you run in PowerShell.

Comment: I meant using only ps... The code above is calling the cmd... Is there a way to do this in ps only?